# Convert a List into a Map with value as a List of Objects in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I have a List of objects which  has duplicate data in it. I would like to convert it into a Map where the key is a String and the value is a List of entities

```
 List<Entity> entityList;
 Map<String, List<Entity> = entityList.stream()
                                           .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entity::getId,????));
```

I am having touble populating the value as a List of entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly use the `groupingBy` collector with a classification function. Here's how it looks.

```
Map<String, List<Entity>> entityById = entityList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entity::getId));
```

Comment: Why you are answering most obvious answer rather mark as duplicate ? Is that is the rule of SO ? Answer and mark as duplicate ? I saw many people comment and mark as duplicate